# Ajax laravel dropdown not returning the id of selected value

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am passing the hotel id as a parameter to my function to get all the rooms in that hotel. But it is returning an error. I want to return in a JSON format the id of the hotel.
this is my javascript function

```
function showRooms($hotel_plan_id) {
   var id = $hotel_plan_id; 
 if (id !== "") {
var token = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content');
     $.ajax({
    url: '/rooms'+id,
    type: "Get",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: "{id:" + JSON.stringify(id) + ", _token:" + token + "}",
success:function(data)
    {
      alert('xdata:' + data);
    //$('#'+dependent).html(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
      alert("Error occur in the rooms()");
    }
 });
```

this is my controller

```
public function rooms(id $id){

    $response = array(); 
    $response =$id;

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/rooms', 'HomeController@rooms')->name('/rooms');
```

Comment: $id = $request->get('id') in controller as you have to pass $request in controller function.

Comment: I changed but still the same error;

Comment: dd($request) and paste here so that i can see your request format.

Comment: I dd($request) it did not dd it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your URL `url: '/rooms'+id,` and `Route::get('/rooms', 'HomeController@rooms')->name('/rooms');` not valid, please see my code i am edited your code

```
   //Change your js function
   function showRooms(hotel_plan_id) {
     var id = hotel_plan_id; 
      if (id !== "") {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          dataType: 'JSON',
          url:'{{ route('rooms', '') }}/'+id,
          data:{_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}'},
          success:function(data){
            alert('xdata:' + data);
            //$('#'+dependent).html(result);
          },
          error: function (result) {
            alert("Error occur in the rooms()");
          }
        });
      }
    }

    //Change your function 
    public function rooms($id){
      return response()->json(['id'=>$id]);
    }

    //Change your route
    Route::get('rooms/{id}', 'HomeController@rooms')->name('rooms');
```

Comment: It is returning [object Object] when I alert the value I am returning do you have any idea?

Comment: use console.log(data) instead of alert('xdata:' + data); and check your browser console or alert('xdata:' + data.id);

Answer (score 1):

```
***Use Route like this in routes.php file:**

Route::get('/rooms', 'HomeController@rooms');


public function rooms(Request $request){
$id = $request->get('id');
$response['id'] = $id;

**Or whatever you want to do and append in response varaible and return** 

return response($response)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
```

Comment: I want to append the id variable to response so I can alert it.

Comment: it is alerting (object Object);